# How to get a user control's type given its path

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic-usercontrols

Is there a way to translate a path to a user control, ~/usercontrols/MyUserControl.ascx, to a type, as in typeof(MyUserControl)?

Answer (score 0):

Use the LoadControl() method on the Page class:

> Loads a Control object from a file based on a specified virtual path. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9ecy7tf.aspx)

```
LoadControl("MyUserControl.ascx").GetType()
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the type without actually instantiating and instance?

Comment: Give BuildManager.GetCompiledType(string virtualPath) a shot (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.buildmanager.getcompiledtype.aspx). Since the use control will be compiled if it was not already a fear there are some security concerns ahead...